# Show different buttons or refresh

Tags: php, jquery

I've been trying to make a like/unlike button for forum posts, I've had some success the code below works but I can't get the page to refresh.

For example - when I click the submit button (like) the database is updated but the unlike button is not shown.
If I refresh the page the unlike button is there now is there a way to do this with jquery so once the like button is clicked it will show the button unlike

```
/* Check Database */
$likes = DB::run("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE id=? AND lid=? AND uid=? AND pid=?", [1, 1, $CURUSER['id'], $row['id']])->fetch();

/* Check Result */
var_export($likes);

/* If No Result Like */
if (!$likes) {
echo
"<form action='' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='like' value='Like' />
</form>";

if(isset($_POST['like']))
{
    DB::run("INSERT INTO likes (id, lid, uid, pid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", [1, 1, $CURUSER['id'], $row['id']]);
}

}

/* If Result UnLike */
if ($likes) {
echo
"<form action='' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='unlike' value='Unlike' />
</form>";

if(isset($_POST['unlike']))
{
DB::run("DELETE FROM likes WHERE id=? AND lid=? AND uid=? AND pid=?", [1, 1, $CURUSER['id'], $row['id']]);
}

}

/* Show Results */
echo '</br>';
echo $likes['id'];
echo $likes['1id'];
echo $likes['uid'];
echo $likes['pid'];
```

Comment: You are SELECTing your data from the database and show the like button based on that, _before_ you even make the INSERT …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database is modified *after* the form is displayed, so the new "like" status is not reflected on the page. One solution is to modify the database *before* checking the "like" status and displaying the form.

Below, I'm refreshing the page after submission by using PHP's [`header`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). It's not absolutely necessary to refresh the page, but it does help to prevent a duplicate submission if the user refreshes. This is known as a [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

> Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) is a web development design pattern that lets the page shown after a form submission be reloaded, shared, or bookmarked without ill effects, such as submitting the form another time.

```
if(isset($_POST['like'])) {
    DB::run("INSERT INTO likes (id, lid, uid, pid) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", [1, 1, $CURUSER['id'], $row['id']]);
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
} elseif (isset($_POST['unlike'])) {
    DB::run("DELETE FROM likes WHERE id=? AND lid=? AND uid=? AND pid=?", [1, 1, $CURUSER['id'], $row['id']]);
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}

/* Check Database */
$likes = DB::run("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE id=? AND lid=? AND uid=? AND pid=?", [1, 1, $CURUSER['id'], $row['id']])->fetch();


if (!$likes) {

    /* If No Result Like */
    echo "<form action='' method='post'>
              <input type='submit' name='like' value='Like' />
          </form>";

} else {

    /* If Result UnLike */
    echo "<form action='' method='post'>
              <input type='submit' name='unlike' value='Unlike' />
          </form>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No one can help you, because we don't see your `$likes` results, here is pseudo code, how it works, where `$likes` are hard-coded to false for begin (it's not liked) and when you click to Like, Unlike button is displayed. After you get this, you should debug what `$likes` contains in each moment and why it didn't enter your if statements:

```
<?php

/* Check Database */
$likes = false;


/* Check Result */
var_export($likes);

/* If No Result Like */
if (!$likes) {
echo
"<form action='' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='like' value='Like' />
</form>";

if(isset($_POST['like']))
{
    $likes = true;
}

}

/* If Result UnLike */
if ($likes) {
echo
"<form action='' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='unlike' value='Unlike' />
</form>";

if(isset($_POST['unlike']))
{
    $likes = false;
}

}

/* Show Results */
```